# Kotlin lambda with several parameters

Tags: java, android, lambda, kotlin

im a bit confused about kotlin lambda expression.
Can not find a proper answer.

In Java i can set a listener with tho parameters like that:

```
myObject.setListener(new MyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean doSmth(int pos, int value) {
             switch(..) {
             ....
             }
            }
})
```

With lambda:

```
 myObject.setListener((p1, p2) -> {
   switch(..) {
    ....
   }
})
```

In Kotlin i can do smth like that:

```
myObject.setListener{p1, p2 -> return@setListener false}
```

or

```
myObject.setListener{{p1, p2 -> 
            if (p1) {
                return@setListener true
            } else {
                return@setListener false
            }
        }}
```

But its really ugly. Is there any way to do it easier?
Of i can use smth like that:

```
myObject.setListener{p1, p2 -> myFunc(p1, p2)}
```

But what if i wanna put my logic into that listener (it could be complex, not just `if else return`)

Comment: You said it is ugly, but compared to what ? Your java version is empty so off course it is cleaner... Can you specified the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your first example, just remove `return@setListener`

```
myObject.setListener{p1, p2 -> false}
```

In your second example, you have to be careful:

1. You have one pair of curly brackets too much `setListener{{` must be `setListener{`. Else you would create a lambda within a lambda.
2. You again just remove the `return`. This is an expression body where the resulting parameter is just used.

   ```
    myObject.setListener{p1, p2 -> 
       if (p1) {
           true
       } else {
           false
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly, you have something like this:

```
fun setListener(f: (Int, Int) -> Boolean) {
    f(1, 2)
}

setListener { p1, p2 -> true }
```

Of course you can extract the logic into another function like this:

```
fun logic (i: Int, i2: Int) :Boolean {
    //complex stuff
    return true
}
setListener(::logic)
```